# T-SQL : calculate total salary of employees

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to calculate the salary for each employee from in period of time for example from 01-01-2021 to 05/31/2021.

I have these 3 tables:

Teacher

| Id | DateOfBirth | Email | PhoneNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0001-01-01 | a@example.com | 23423424 |
| 2 | 1984-09-30 | b@example.com | 9832131 |

TeacherSalary

| Id | Salary | TeacherId | FromDate | ToDate | IsPartTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 500000 | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-31 | 1 |
| 2 | 10000000 | 1 | 2021-02-01 | 2021-03-15 | 0 |
| 3 | 15000000 | 1 | 2021-03-16 | NULL (mean now) | 0 |

TimeEntry

| Id | TeacherId | TeacherSalaryPartTime | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 500000 | 2021-01-05 |
| 2 | 1 | 450000 | 2021-01-07 |

I want to calculate total salary of these employee

For example in this case, this employee have from 01/01/2021 to 01/31/2021 is part-time then sum from time Entry (500000+450000)

and 02/01/2021 to 03/15/2021 is (number days in feb)*(10000000/number days in feb) + 15 days of March with salary calculated is 10000000/(day of month March)*(day from 03/01/2021 to 03/15/2021)

and 03/16/2021 to 05/31/2021 is calculated with this: (number days from 03/16/2021 to end of month)*(15000000/number of days in March) + (number days from 04/01/2021 to 05/31/2021)*(15000000/number of days)

Could you please help me calculate this in T-SQL

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried yourself and why is it not working for you? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68013668/edit) your question to include your personal attempt.

Comment: Please also tag the version of `SQL Server` you are using

Comment: Note that for our purposes, an id like '98' is no less comprehensible than an id like '98A98136-816F-4637-680F-08D930A8EE53'.

Comment: The format of the [Date] columns is a bit suspicious, what is the datatype?

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's datetime(2), and for full it's "1989-12-17 00:00:00.0000000" format,  (where did your 05/31/2021 come from?) i'd like to created an store-procedure with 2 parameter FromDate and Todate

Answer (score 1):

There you go

```
DECLARE @StartDate  DATE = '2021-01-01',
        @EndDate    DATE = '2021-05-31'


SELECT  Teacher.Id                      AS Id,
        Teacher.FullName                AS FullName,
        (
            SELECT  SUM(TimeEntry.TeacherSalaryPartTime)    AS  SalarySum
            FROM    TimeEntry
            WHERE   TimeEntry.EntryDate         BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
            AND     TimeEntry.TeacherId         =       Teacher.Id
        )
        +
        (
            SELECT  SUM(
                        TeacherSalary.Salary *
                        (DATEDIFF(
                            MONTH, 
                            GREATEST(@StartDate, TeacherSalary.FromDate),
                            LEAST(@EndDate, ISNULL(TeacherSalary.ToDate, @EndDate))
                        ) + 1)
                    )                                   AS  SalarySum
            FROM    TeacherSalary
            WHERE   TeacherSalary.IsPartTime    =       0
            AND     TeacherSalary.FromDate      >=      @StartDate
            AND     TeacherSalary.ToDate        <=      @EndDate
            AND     TeacherSalary.TeacherId     =       Teacher.Id
        )

FROM    Teacher
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. You might want to check the "now" (where did your 05/31/2021 come from?) and the datediff formula to tune if you have for example half a month, what to do.

```
select
     t.Id
    ,sum(subquery1.[sum]) as [sum]
from
    Teacher t
    left join TeacherSalary s on s.TeacherId=t.Id
    outer apply
    (
        select 
            case
                when s.IsPartTime=0 then s.Salary * (1+datediff(month,s.FromDate,isnull(s.ToDate,'20210531')))
                when s.IsPartTime=1 then 
                    (
                        select sum(e.TeacherSalaryPartTime) 
                        from    
                            [Time Entry] e 
                        where 
                            e.TeacherId=t.Id
                    )
            end
                as [sum]
    ) as subquery1
    group by t.Id
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's datetime(2), and for full it's "1989-12-17 00:00:00.0000000" format, (where did your 05/31/2021 come from?) i'd like to created an store-procedure with 2 parameter FromDate and Todate and 05/31/2021 is example of ToDate